# If $a^{2/3}=b^{2/3}$, then....

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

If we solve the math in the following way,

$$\Big(\frac{a}{b}\Big)^{2/3 } =1$$

Now cube both side we have, 
$$\Big(\frac{a}{b}\Big)^{2} =1$$

From this conclusion, can we say that, only the option $a=2/3$ is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While $\frac{a}{b} = 1$ **could** be true, it doesn't **have** to be true. For all we know, it might be the case that $a = -8$ and $b = 8$ (after all, it satisfies the initial equation and constraints). Another possibility is that $a = b = 8$, which rules out the possibility that $\frac{a}{b}$ must **always** equal $-1$.

The only safe choices that we know for sure must always be true (given that $b \neq 0$) are:

- $\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^2 = 1$
- $a^2 = b^2$

Comment: Why the last one is not true? Is it because, there is a possibility to have a negative root?

Comment: See $a=1$, $b=-1$. notice that $a^{\frac{2}{3}}=b^{\frac{2}{3}}$. is $\sqrt{a}=\sqrt{b}$?